# Power BI M RangeStart

Tags: powerbi, m

Working on an incremental refresh from SalesForce to a PBI report. I found a code snippet from the Cross Join Blog that could solve my issue. However, I'm getting errors. First, there was:

```
Expression.Error: The name 'RangeStart' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.
```

I created a new data call, but got:

```
PBI Expression.Error: The import RangeStart matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
    //Find the current date and time when this query runs
    CurrentDateTime = DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow(),
    //Find yesterday's date
    PreviousDay = Date.AddDays(DateTime.Date(CurrentDateTime), -1),

    // Put the current date and time in a new column in the table
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "UTC Data Load Date", each CurrentDateTime),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"UTC Data Load Date", type datetimezone}}),
    // Add the filter required for incremental refresh
    // Only return rows in this table if:
    // a) The RangeStart parameter equals yesterday's date, and
    // b) RangeEnd is not null (which should never be true)
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type4", each DateTime.Date(RangeStart)=PreviousDay and RangeEnd<>null)
```

It may have something to do with the way CurrentDateTime

```
2023-08-16T13:10:00.5815997+00:00
```

and PreviousDay

```
8/15/2023
```

are formatted, but I do not have enough experience with M code to know how to fix that and my thought could be wildly wrong as the code snippet worked in the example given. I am working in Desktop.